# Containers en StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

hace unas semanas vengo con la siguiente duda:

Al crear un Container ( utilizando el connect en un componente de vista al que se le quiere poner un logica utilizando redux) por ejemplo un HeaderContainer que tenga un boton que llame a un dispatch que haga alguna cosa,si lo combino con StackNavigator y me muevo entre pantallas las cuales tiene cada una su HeaderContainer al hacer click en el boton se "dispachean" la cantidad de veces que hay de vistas en la stack(se deberia hacer un solo dispatch pero como las demas vistas no finalizaron su ciclo de vida del componente y estan en la stack sucede esto).
Tienen idea como se puede solucionar para que no pase esto?

Estos serian los HeaderContainer de cada pantalla
[image]

Al hacer click se lanzan varios dispatch
[image]

Este es﻿ un caso especifico pero me pasa con todos los containers al ir apilando vistas en la stack de la navegacion.

Comment: Imagino que usas el header como `navigatorOptions`; en ese caso, el header sería compartido en cada vista, haciéndose click en cada vista del stack. No estoy seguro si hay un fix para esto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta,hace rato esperaba que alguien me pudiera responer la duda y si como dices pasa eso.Pense que habia alguna manera "profesional" de resolver esto porque se utiliza generealmente el  StackNavigator para poder ir navegando entre las ventanas pero sucede esto al utilizar Redux...no solo pasa con el HeaderContainer sino con los containers que este dentro de la ventana a mostrar...